# Trigger on ListEmail or Children records?

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks

I'm trying to run some custom code when a list email is sent but I'm noticing the after insert trigger I have on Task does not run. I'm also unable to create a trigger on the ListEmail object. Has anyone found a way around this limitation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Mass email actions [do not invoke triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm):

> Some operations don’t invoke triggers.
>   Triggers are invoked for data manipulation language (DML) operations that the Java application server initiates or processes. Therefore, some system bulk operations don't invoke triggers. Some examples include:
>
> ...
>   - Mass email actions

Unfortunately, you're going to be stuck with Scheduled Apex for operations built around list emails.