# Trigger from ListEmail- workaround?

Tags: apex, trigger

I would like to set up an apex trigger after a ListEmail is sent. However, i am seeing that ListEmail object is not a choice in the list of trigger objects. There is only "ListEmailChangeEvent". I am not familiar with that trigger. What would be an example of how I could use the ListEmailChangeEvent object trigger to fire after a ListEmail is sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240368/trigger-on-listemail-or-children-records), Mass email actions do not invoke triggers and a way mentioned in the thread is to use schedulable apex.

Comment: Thank you- that is good to know